# Advice on how to refactor spring mvc into plain servlets or jetty handler

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jetty

I have a spring mvc app that I want to refactor out, speficially removing the spring related code and wiring.

It is a simple spring mvc at this point, so the key things I have to do our dependancy injection.

My application.xml has wirings for my Dao objects, injecting the datasource into my Dao objects.

**How can I use a spring agnostic DI now?  What do I have to change? I want to use guice unless you guys recommend otherwise**

application.xml:

```
<bean id="userDao" class="com.blah.dao.UserDaoImpl">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

**What do you suggest I use to setup my datasource and connection pooling now?**

The actual page/url mapping is specific to if I choose servlets or a jetty handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard annotation `@Inject` for dependency injection. Both Spring and [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections) support it.